# Codeigniter 4 : Model vs Entity Classes

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, frameworks, entity

In the Codeigniter documentation:

In the Data Modeling section, there are two options:

- Using Models
- Using Entity Classes

I can't quite understand the role of each of these things, such as when to use them, and how to apply them properly.

I would like to get an explanation of the function and purpose of Entity Classes in Codeigniter 4.

Comment: This looks like a good content seeding question. I don't see any duplicates for this question. @List, you are a rare recipient of a question uv!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I quite understand the difference between the two.

Surely Codeigniter provides these two options for a reason.

What I want to know is,
How can I implement both correctly.